# Cannot send Ajax request because of CORS from my UI app to API app even CORS on API is enabled

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-core, cors, startup, .net-core-3.1

I have to apps that is located on one origin but they have different ports
One is UI, second is API
When I send requests from 'postman' or from my browser, response code is 200 and all is OK
But when I send request throw ajax from my UI app from browser I get failed request because of Cors
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vsM5.jpg)

If it's need, in Startup I have Cors policy and use it. This is ConfigureServices Method

```html
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                x => x.MigrationsAssembly("CRM.API")));

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder
                            .AllowAnyOrigin()
                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                            .AllowAnyHeader();
                        //.AllowCredentials();
                    });
            });

            services.AddHangfire(x => x.UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddScoped<IEmailBirthdayManager, EmailBirthdayManager>();
            services.AddSingleton<IAccessManager, AccessManager>();

            services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);

            //services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            //    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "CRM.API", Version = "v1" });
                c.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First());
            });
        }
```

There is Configure method

```html
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseSwagger();


            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
            });

            //            app.UseMiddleware<AuthorizationMiddleware>();

            app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
            {
                Authorization = new[] { new HangfireDashboardAuthorizationFilter()}
            });

            app.UseHangfireServer();

            HangfireJobScheduler.ScheduleReccuringJobs();

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors("AllowAll");

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Departments}/{action=GetDepartments}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

And also there is ajax Request to api

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
$.ajax({
        url: `https://p-host-crm-2.hostco.ru:1337/api/users/getUserByLogin/gorbunov`,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("Data Loaded: ");
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

What is more I tried to Use `[EnableCors("AllowAll")]` in my method and controller
Tried use `AddDefaultPolicy" code and "app.UseCors()`
Tried use `SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)`

If you ask me what web-server I use, I answer: IIS
In the settings of IIS I haven't found anything

And any suggestions and solutions from internet haven't helped me

Waiting for your answers!

Comment: Try adding app.UseMvc() at the end of the configure method

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Answer (score 0):

in web config you have to enable cors:`config.EnableCors();`
and then you have to set origins using attribute on above controller class
:`[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]`